# What is an example of a non-simple finite extension $K/F$ such that the purely inseparable closure of $F$ in $K$ is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

The standard example of a finite extension that is not simple is to take $k$ to be a field of characteristic $p > 0$ and consider $k(x,y)$ over $k(x^p,y^p)$. In this case, the extension is purely inseparable too.

I was wondering the following:

> Is it possible to construct a finite extension of fields $K/F$ which is not simple and such that the purely inseparable closure of $F$ in $K$ is simple?

The purely inseparable closure of $F$ in $K$, denoted $I$, is defined to be the set of all $\alpha \in K$ that are purely inseparable over $F$. Similarly, the separable closure of $F$ in $K$ is denoted $S$ and is defined to be the set of all $\alpha \in K$ that are separable over $F$. One can show that $I$ and $S$ are subfields of $K$ containing $F$.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to construct, or even search for, such an extension?

I know that we cannot have $SI = K$, because [we can show](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/431756/279515) from the hypotheses that $SI$ is a simple extension of $F$. In particular, $K$ cannot be normal over $F$ (see Proposition V.6.11 in Lang's *Algebra*, page 251, third edition). Moreover, $F$ cannot be perfect because every algebraic extension of a perfect field is separable (see Corollary V.6.12 in Lang's *Algebra*, page 252, third edition), so in particular $F$ cannot be a finite field or have characteristic $0$. Moreover, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18210/82537) by @KConrad on MathOverflow shows that every finite extension of $\Bbb{F}_p(x)$ is simple, so these are also ruled out as candidates for $F$.

I haven't been able to make any progress beyond this, though. I've tried fiddling around with the above standard example of $k(x,y)/k(x^p,y^p)$, but no matter how I make $K/F$ non-simple I end up with a non-simple purely inseparable closure. Maybe it's because the only example I know of a non-simple extension is the one mentioned at the beginning that I don't know how to create new examples.

I spent a bit of time trying to prove that no such extension could exist, but could not make any progress there either. Any help is appreciated.

---

This question is inspired by the problem asked here: [A finite extension is simple iff the purely inseparable closure is simple?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1931453/279515). Any such example of extension fields $K/F$ would provide a counter-example to the claim in the title of the linked question.